# React Router useHistory hook returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use useHistory from react-router-dom when I click a button, but it returns undefined, so I can't push the new page url.

[image]

My component is an inner component of a Route as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

This is my simple Login component code:

```
export default function Login() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function onEnterAsGuest() {
    history.push("/example");
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Logo></Logo>
      <WelcomeTextContainer>
        <StyledHeading>Welcome!</StyledHeading>
      </WelcomeTextContainer>
      <ButtonContainer>
        <Button
          primary
          text={"Enter as guest"}
          onClick={onEnterAsGuest}
          block
        />
      </ButtonContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

This is how I instantiate the Router:

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

...

export default function App() {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {Routes(width)}

        <Route path="*">
          <p>
            Wrong path! Return to <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
          </p>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This is how I define my Routes:

```
export default function Routes(width: number) {
  return routes.map((route) => {
    return (
      <Route exact path={route.path} key={route.path}>
        {width > 720
          ? DesktopVersion(route.component)
          : MobileVersion(route.component)}
      </Route>
    );
  });
}
```

And this is the `routes` object I loop through:

```
const routes: IRoute[] = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: "/example",
    component: () => (
      <p style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
        <Link to="/another" style={{ color: "salmon" }}>
          This is a link
        </Link>
      </p>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "/another",
    component: () => (
      <p>
        <Link to="/example" style={{ color: "salmon" }}>
          Hello world
        </Link>
      </p>
    ),
  },
];
```

Could you please help me to debug this? Don't know where else to check for errors...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's see your route file

Comment: These are the versions:

`react@17.0.1` | `react-dom@17.0.1` | `react-router-dom@5.2.0`

Comment: Just added the Routes definition to the initial description

Comment: No, I don't have that package. I import everything from `react-router-dom`, and my Router is HashRouter

Comment: That worked perfectly! thanks @AjeetShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't call the component as a function.**

Use `<Routes width={width}/>` instead of `{Routes(width)}`.